# IE ReceiveTimeout Affecting .NET Application

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, timeout, registry

So I just took over support of a new application at work and I'm having trouble with timeouts. After endless research and fiddling around I have managed to find the fault which lies with IE's default ReceiveTimeout settings. I have been able to adjust this settings by editing my registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/InternetSettings) but I can't do this for our end-users as their company policy does not allow this. Is there a way that I can control this at an application level. Perhaps like adding something to my Web Config that will allow our application to exceed IE's default?